# Should Training,test and validation data sets should be independent of each other in neural networks?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, independence, artificial-intelligence

I have a dataset of n items and i draw three samples of equal size. These three samples are training set,test set and validation set. 
I want to use this data for training ,testing and to check overfitting(that i don't traing my model too much).

All these samples are drawn from same population.

Now my question is that should these samples be independent of each other? What are the requirements for data to be good enough for training purpose?

What i undestood so far if they are not independent then i am implicitly training my model also on training set and validation set.  Any help would be great.

Comment: The test set should be completely separate from the training and validation data: it is supposed to be data you have not yet seen when producing your model.

Comment: The validation set can be part of the training data, but you use one part for validation and the rest for training, so similarly separate at that stage.  But you can validate several times, as in cross-validation, and once you have tuned your model, you can use the full training set (including that used for validation) to create your final model

Comment: @Henry When you say completely different, does that mean a t-test of training and test set will be enough?

Comment: No - it means that you should not be sampling the same items from your dataset for the test set as you have already sampled for your training and validation set